# Strategy for storing data from a web API locally

Tags: python, pandas, api

Let's say I access some business data like sales orders and invoices from a web API and I want to do things with them like populate a sales dashboard in a Google Sheet. This web API has strict rate limiting and their pagination only allows for 10 results per call.

Instead of writing a script that retrieves all of the data at once to update my dashboard every morning, what kind of strategy can I research that will allow me to cache or store the data either locally or in something like bigquery so that I can just retrieve any new transactions from the web API every day? I'd also like to be able to quickly pull all of the data into pandas for one-off reporting purposes instead of retrieving it all from the web API because it's slow and costly.

Comment: some APIs may have function to filter data and get only newer than some date/time or some ID number - and then you have to only use ID which you already have to get only newer values - and older values you should keep in database, csv or whatever you like to have all values after reading only new values. If API doesn't have this function then you will have to read all data again and check if you already have it - and if you have it then stop geting data from API. And there is no method to cache it or make it faster.

Comment: Got it. Yes I could filter by time or ID to get only new data with this API. I didn't know if there was some particularly recommended way to go about this. I'm retrieving Quickbooks database tables in json and I'm probably just overthinking it. I could store those in json text files in google cloud and be done with it. Thanks for the input.